# How do I open a .bat containing a GUI in a java program in Linux?

Tags: java, linux, batch-file, runtime

everyone. I'm quite new here so please be tolerant if I make any mistakes.

I have a .bat file containing a command line to open up a .jar file that contains a program that has a GUI in it. The only line that's in the .bat file is:

```
    java -jar "NewServer.jar"
```

I've been trying to use Runtime() to get this to run, but most the instructions I find to open a .bat file in a java program are for Windows. I'm currently using Fedora 12 (don't tell me to upgrade, I can't) if that makes a difference and programming using Eclipse. I also found this ProcessBuilder thing, but I couldn't get it to work so unless you have very explicit directions on how to use it, please don't include it in your answer. I would much rather use Runtime. It looked simpler.

Here's my code to test using Runtime in a java program. I'm hoping that if I can get this to work, I can get it to work in my real program.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class testbat {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Process proc = null;
    try {
        proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./ myServer.bat");
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

      System.out.println("Cool");


}
```

The last line is just there for me to see if the program actually ran in case the GUI doesn't open. Also, I've already tried many combinations of things to include in the area after ".exec". I've tried using a path like "~/user/workspace/ProjectServer/dist/myServer.bat" to no avail.

I also already know that .bat files are for windows, but I'm able to execute it in linux, so I don't know if that makes a difference. I also tried using a .sh file the same way and it didn't work.

Please bear in mind that I'm not that great at Java, but I had to use it for this particular program, so if your answers could be really descriptive that would be awesome.

Comment: bat files only work in Windows, not in Unix or other OS's. Answer: don't do this.

Comment: could you elaborate on the "to no avail" part. Did the "Cool" print? Did you get a stack trace before that? Also there should be no space between the '/' and 'm' in "./ myServer.bat"

Comment: Well... to be fair, it doesn't really matter what it's called, it's just misleading to run a `.bat` file in unix.

Comment: When you say, "I'm hoping that if I can get this to work, I can get it to work in my real program," are you saying the calling program is just an example, or that your unfortunately-named script that loads a GUI is just an example?

Comment: @PeterT: the "cool" did print, but that's all it did. The GUI didn't open up.

Comment: @phatfingers: I need to have this GUI program that is in a separate java file open up in a server program. The code above is just a test program to see if I can even get a GUI to open up, much less try put it into my server program that is unrelated to this question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Alright, if I don't want to use .bat files, what do you suggest I do instead? I need an executable .jar to open up in a different Java program. It has a GUI in it that I need to fully run my final program. What is above is just a test.

Comment: @GravityKitty: you've already been told what you need to do in the answers below.

Comment: @GravityKitty: I'm not sure you understood my submitted answer, but no matter how you name your called script or what goes into it, your Process doesn't actually run when you call "exec()", and you need to run proc.waitfor() on the next line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just take that line out of the bat file, and run it.  Yo're making it too hard.

```
$ java -jar "NewServer.jar"
```

will work.  The quotes aren't necessary, so

```
$ java -jar NewServer.jar
```

will work as well.  If you want to have the equivalent of your bat file, create a file named, say, `run_newserver`  containing that line.  Change its mode to executable:

```
$ cat > run_newserver
java -jar NewServer.jar
^D
$ chmod a+x run_newserver
$ ./run_newserver
```

Ideally, since you shouldn't have scripts without comments,  do this.  In your favorite editor, create a file run_newserver containing

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
java -jar NewServer.jar
```

and `chmod` that.  The line with `#!` -- often called a "shebang line" -- is UNIX magic that lets you say what interpreter you want.  The program `env` in `usr/bin` finds your program and runs it (needed because different systems put `bash` in different directories.)

You *could* even put explanatory comments in the file too.

I'm a little unclear why you want to use Runtime#exec to run it at all -- it seems you'll just need a shell script to start *that* program.

Comment: Well, I'm starting that program directly in Eclipse. While I'm running that program, I want it to open up another .java that was stored in a .jar. This other program contains a GUI I made. Please bear in mind that the code above in my question is just a test to see if I can open up the GUI in another program.

My "real" program is actually going to be a server for a test taking program. The server has to open up a GUI to create the test so that a client can connect to the server and take it.

Comment: Okay, well, there's a couple things to be careful about, and a question to ask -- where is your GUI going to *go*?  If you run it on the server, which is what you get from Runtime#exec, it's (at best) going to show up on the server's console.  Maybe you could explain (possibly in another question) what you're really trying to do?

Comment: I plan on the GUI opening in its own window. I don't want it to open up in console, obviously. I can get the GUI to open up normally on its own in a separate window when it's not embedded into a program. The GUI isn't really interacting with the server. I just have it included in the server program so that I don't have multiple files. Anything the GUI is reading is text files, not lines of code from the server program.

Comment: The real issue is whether you're on the same machine as the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using Java to run a Batch file, that in turn runs a Java program?  Why have Batch in the loop at all?  Just put the jar in your classpath and call it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Batch (.bat) files are only for Windows environment. So, Try using shell script

```
 Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("myServer.sh");
```

Comment: I have already tried this and it didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just open up terminal and do this

```
vi /dir/to/exec/exec.sh
```

tap "i" and write this

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar "NewServer.jar"
```

or if you want to run it in the background

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar "NewServer.jar" & > /tmp/JavaServer.log
```

hit esc and type ":wq" and you have saved the file.

type this into the terminal

```
chmod +x /dir/to/exec/exec.sh
```

this give executable privileges and then you should run the file like

```
sh /dir/to/exec/exec.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Process is only initialized by your first call.  You need to run:

```
proc.waitfor();
```

to get it to actually run your app.

Comment: You're likely to bump into other issues as well.  Your Process thread outputs to stdin and stderr, which your calling app needs to consume or your child app may hang.  See http://www.pojava.org/howto/process.html for an easy approach (source code is available on SourceForge and Maven repositories if you want to DIY).